# Is there a reason to include a virtual network in a cloud native Azure solution?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to understand if there is added value by including a virtual network in a cloud native Azure solution.

For example, let's say I am hosting a web app on Azure App Services. I am able to connect my web app to a an Azure storage account for saving data. I also connect my Azure account to Azure Key Vault for storing secrets.

Is there any added value or security by adding an Azure Virtual Network to my back-end (storage + key vault)?

Answer (score 0):

I think with VNet Integration v2 for App Services there is some value (traffic won't use public internet to access other Azure PaaS offerings if you configure VNet 
services endpoints\firewall of those PaaS offerings). But not much for VNet integration v1.

Realistically there is very little gain (unless you are paranoid about security) in doing so, at least in the App Services case.

Key Vault bit has more benefits and those are not only security benefits, but easier key\secret\configuration management. which is tangible.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely good reasons to put your Azure resources into a vnet.

In most cases you will have back-end resources that should not be publicly exposed to the Internet, but do need to be accessible to other resources in your application.

You can

A) Create firewall rules for each resource specifying which public IP addresses can access it.

or

B) Put the resources into a vnet which will isolate all of them from the public Internet by default and use Network Security Groups to control which resources can access other resources, and specify those which should be accessible from the public Internet.

For a very simple application with a handful of resources there may not be a huge difference between these two approaches, but as your cloud presence grows, and with it the number of applications, services and infrastructure components, it will become more and more difficult to manage the security.

Using a vnet with Network Security Groups will make it easier to configure and maintain security rules between your components as your environment becomes more complex, so it's a good practice to build this into the architecture at the start.

[Here is a good blog post on the topic](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/03/04/why-are-azure-virtual-networks-important-for-developers/)